# Get Last element of splitted string

Tags: javascript

My problem:

I have a path like this fore example: `some/path/with/unknown/depth`

In this example i want to access `depth`.

I know i can do it like this:

```
let path = "some/path/with/unknown/depth";

let word = path.split("/")[4];
```

But `4` is hardcoded. Is there any way to get the last element dynamically? One solution could be this here:

```
let path = "some/path/with/unknown/depth";

let words = path.split("/");

let word = words[words.length - 1];
```

Is it possible to get the last element just with 1 line?

Comment: `'some/path/with/unknown/depth'.split('/').slice(-1)` might work?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yea it works, thats what i looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello here's my trick for doing this :)

```js
let path = "some/path/with/unknown/depth";
let result = path.split('/').reverse()[0]
console.log(result);
```